# How to scale `gatsby-image` by height?

Tags: gatsby

I'm working on an component that needs to have `n` images side-by-side with a fixed height of `60vh` (so no fixed pixel value that I know beforehand). The problem is, that these images are of different orientations (some landscape, some portrait) and thus aspect ratios. So every image needs to be as wide as is needed to reach the defined height. The fluid option seems to be built for the exact opposite.

How could I pull that off? I could also live with forking the library locally or whatever else I need to do.

Comment: Here is a maxHeight attribute https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-image/#fluid-image-query-parameters. Does specifying only the maxHeight not work?

Comment: Thanks, but it only expects `Int`s, and even if I would set like `1000`, the `maxWidth` has a default of `800` with no way to unset it. :/

Comment: @air did you end up figuring this out?